# ImportError: No module named pymysql in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, importerror, pymysql

I have flask web application running on aws, my app.py file gives error for "import pymysql" line (whole application is working fine.)

Error.log
[Sat Jul 29 06:12:54.545904 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 28317:tid 140546426812160] [client ] ImportError: No module named pymysql

Python version is -
2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

I created test.py file and executed, it worked and displays rows from database which is on RDS , So no idea why same thing is not working on app.py file , both using same python

> ```
> **$pip list**
> click (6.7)
> Flask (0.12.2)
> Flask-MySQL (1.4.0)
> itsdangerous (0.24)
> Jinja2 (2.9.6)
> MarkupSafe (1.0)
> pip (8.1.1)
> PyMySQL (0.7.11)
> setuptools (20.7.0)
> Werkzeug (0.12.2)
> wheel (0.29.0)
> ```

```
<hname@ip>:/usr/local/lib/python2.7$ ls
dist-packages  site-packages

> <hname@ip>:/usr/local/lib/python2.7$ ls dist-packages/ click          
> itsdangerous.py click-6.7.dist-info                itsdangerous.pyc
> flask                              jinja2 Flask-0.12.2.dist-info      
> Jinja2-2.9.6.dist-info flaskext                           markupsafe
> Flask_MySQL-1.4.0.dist-info        MarkupSafe-1.0.egg-info
> Flask_MySQL-1.4.0-py3.5-nspkg.pth  werkzeug itsdangerous-0.24.egg-info
> Werkzeug-0.12.2.dist-info

<hname@ip>:/usr/local/lib/python2.7$ ls site-packages/
<hname@ip>:/usr/local/lib/python2.7$
```

I also have same application on my laptop with python 3.5.2 and working without any issue...

Tried a lot no clue ...

Answer (score 4):

> This bug have also been giving me some grey hair ^^

I use python2 and the solution for me, was to install the package with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pymysql
```

If you are using python3, then you can install it with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql
```

Comment: This works on me for 2.7 python version. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

try the following command.

`pip install PyMySQL==0.7.11`

What come back?

Comment: Thank god,I get `No module named _markerlib` error at all times.now i knonw the reason is new version of pyMySQL is not compatible with python2.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

installing with this command did not work
$sudo pip install PyMySql

I have to do

```
$sudo -i
$sudo pip install PyMySql
```

And it worked...

Answer (score 0):

update pip and reinstall PyMySQL