# Ansible - pip not found

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am getting this error:

```
    TASK [pip] *********************************************************************
    failed: [default] (item=urllib3) => 
{"changed": false, "item": "urllib3", 
"msg": "Unable to find any of pip2, pip to use.  pip needs to be installed."}
```

Upon a suggestion I run following command:

```
ansible default -a "which pip"
```

I get an error:

```
default | FAILED | rc=1 >>
non-zero return code
```

So I guess that means no pip installed. I tried installing pip using:

```
ansible default -a "easy_install pip"
```

I get the following error:

```
default | FAILED | rc=2 >>
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
In play_local.yaml, I have the following task:

```
- name: Prepare system
  hosts: default
  become: yes
  gather_facts: false
  pre_tasks:
    - raw: sudo apt-get -y install python python-setuptools python-pip build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev easyinstall pip
    - file: path=/etc/sudoers.d/ssh-auth-sock state=touch mode=0440
      #- lineinfile: line='Defaults env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"' path=/etc/sudoers.d/ssh-auth-sock
    - replace:
        path: /etc/apt/sources.list
        regexp: 'br.'
        replace: ''
```

Shouldn't this task install pip?

Comment: What OS your target node is?

Comment: I am using mac and the node is ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be pip is hashed. Meaning pip is installed at path x (may be `/usr/local/bin/pip`), however, cached at path y (may be `/usr/bin/pip)`. You can confirm that from - `ansible default -m shell -a ‘type pip’`. To resolve this you’ll need to run - `ansible default -m shell -a ‘hash -r’`.

BTW, you can also use command module instead of shell.

Comment: Just replace shell with command. See - https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ansible/commands/

Comment: After I run the command: default | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
pip is /usr/local/bin/pip

Comment: @Eduardo great. So you have the pip. Did you try running hash -r command, like I had it mentioned in my answer ? That should resolve the issue

Comment: It worked!, can you explain me why this could happen?

Comment: pip was installed at /usr/local/bin/pip and it was cached at /usr/bin/pip. On running command hash -r you cleared the cache and pip worked again.

Answer (score 9):

Seems like pip is not installed, you can use the following task to install it:

```
- name: Install pip
  apt:
    name: python-pip
    update_cache: yes
    state: present
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will give it a try, I added an update to the question, shouldn't that task install pip?

Comment: I have added that task then run vagrant provision, but still same error

Comment: This may work better for you. The cache likely needs updating:

```
- name: install pip
  apt:
    name: python-pip
    update_cache: yes
    state: present
```

Comment: This didn't work for me! Had to follow --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45386971/importerror-no-module-named-pymysql-in-python-2-7

Answer (score 0):

I've just met the same problem on a brand new CentOS 7. Solved through installing `setuptools` with `yum` first and then `pip` with `easy_install` as below :

```
ansible default -b -m yum -a "name=python-setuptools state=present"
ansible default -b -m easy_install -a "name=pip state=present"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Debian Based systems (RUN THIS ON CLIENT SYSTEMS):
first install package *python-is-python3* then add alias for pip *echo alias pip=pip3 >> ~/.bashrc*

I know my solution would be dumb but It works.

```yaml
# pip-fix.yml
- name: pip fix
  hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: install python-is-python3
      apt: name=python-is-python3 update_cache=yes state=present
    - name: creating alias
      shell: echo alias pip=pip3 >> ~/.bashrc

    - name: test and upgrade pip
      pip: name=pip state=latest
      tags:
        - packages
```

run using `ansible-playbook pip-fix.yml`

Answer (score 0):

## Ansible Not finding / Installing Pip

While not using the author's original details, i think this might help them or others.

I was getting the following error for installing pip:

- via Ansible:

  > FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/bin/easy_install --upgrade pip", "failed": true, "msg": "Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
- directly on the host:

  > Searching for pip
  > Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
  > Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
  > Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
  > Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  > No local packages or download links found for pip
  > error: Could not find suitable distribution for
  > Requirement.parse('pip')

I attempted to use the above `hash -r` answer:
(NOTE: help hash... hash -r == forget all remembered locations)

```
- name: forget easy_install path
  shell: hash -r
  become: true
```

however this was not a solve for me.

I found via another post: ['pip install' fails for every package ("Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748063/pip-install-fails-for-every-package-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies) that this was the final fix:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

or

```
- name: manually install pip
  shell: curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py | python
  become: true
```

NOTE: i changed the pip version. Also, there is a better way to do a curl in ansible, this is simply an example

I then followed with the `easy_install pip` latest. to ensure it was up to date.

Answer (score 0):

below fix worked for me

#ln -s /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip