# Ansible Playbook can't find pip in virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ansible

I am using a basic Ansible Playbook in order to install some Python packages on a Ubuntu 18.04 system. For the sake of demonstration, take the following example playbook `test.yml`.

```
---
- name: Installing demo package.
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Installing with pip.
    pip:
      name:
        - "numpy"
      virtualenv: "venv"
      virtualenv_python: python3.6
```

I installed a virtual environment using `python3 -m venv venv` and activated it using `source venv/bin/activate/`. However, if I run `ansible-playbook test.yml`, I get the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "venv/bin/pip install numpy", "msg": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory", "rc": 2}
```

**Error analysis:**

I ran a couple of commands from the [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997637/ansible-pip-not-found).

`ansible localhost -a "which pip"` returns:

```
localhost | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
/home/mydir/venv/bin/pip
```

I tried to clear the hash using `ansible localhost -m shell -a "hash -r"` and obtained

```
localhost | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
```

Afterwards, `ansible localhost -m shell -a "type pip""` returns:

```
localhost | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
pip is /home/mydir/venv/bin/pip
```

But nevertheless, the problem persists, even though I could install numpy using `venv/bin/pip install numpy` in a shell without any disturbances.

The version of Ansible is 2.5.1.